confusion matrix plotting only one side for predict model
I'm having an issue with the matrix to show the predicted labels for binary output of text classification. It's showing that all the predictions are falling under a single class and are not plotting prediction for class 1. I have honestly no idea where I have gone wrong.
threshold = 0.5

y_pred_prob = cnn_model.predict(x_test_pad)

y_pred = (y_pred_prob > threshold).astype(int).flatten()

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

con_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class, labels = [0,1])


disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = con_mat, display_labels = [0,1])
disp.plot(cmap='Blues')
plt.show()

This is the output I am currently getting.
Incorrect matrix classification

I see your predictions are stored in a variable called y_pred but the predictions you are passing to the confusion matrix is a variable called y_pred_class.
